# Flash Drive will not mount, boot, or format

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a flash drive which I `dd`'d a build of Chrome OS onto, and now I cannot format, mount, or boot the drive. I have tried using Disk Utility on:

- Snow Leopard: (POSIX reports: The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot allocate memory)
- and using "Computer Management" on Windows XP (Stops at "Formatting: 100%").

How can I fix this flash drive?

Comment: Please detail what happens (error messages, etc.) when you attempt to format it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, right click (My) Computer, click Manage and go to Disk Management and see if you can wipe and/or format the drive from there. This solves most problems, but if you're still stuck, leave a comment and I'll see what other options there are. :)

If none of the tools is able to format the drive, it's possible that the drive is just faulty. In that case you're best of just getting a new one.

Comment: That didn't work... it stops at "Formatting: 100%"

Comment: Try burning a Live CD of GParted and formatting it from there, it's got me out of a few binds in the past: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: I actually tried that and it wouldn't boot - AND it could have been the reason I had to reinstall my OS!

Comment: I think what I'd resort to using would be this: http://hddguru.com/software/2006.04.12-HDD-Low-Level-Format-Tool/ - after which I'd try to use Disk Management again. Can I just check though, have you tried other USB ports at all?

Comment: Yes, I've tried multiple USB ports. I'll try the HDDGuru.

Comment: The HDDGuru didn't work - it took a while and was giving errors the whole time, like "Format error at offset _x_" When it finally completed, there was no apparent change to the drive.

Comment: My guess is the drive has had its day, but by all means get a second opinion. For reference there are a lot of counterfeit Kingston USB sticks on the market that report the wrong capacity and fail during a format. Make sure your stick is genuine, some are very convincing (hologram stickers are cloned too!).

Comment: It was almost brand new, and it came preloaded with stuff which I immediately removed and installed Chrome OS for fun using `dd`. So it actually hasn't "had its day" :) It worked before, though.

Comment: I'd still say it's worth checking whether it's legit. In any case, if it's fairly new, depending on your country you should be entitled to a replacement.

Comment: +1 - Good information for Windows. It solved my issue, thanks.